# Accessing the /cache directory in the Android filesystem

Tags: android, caching, directory-permissions

How can I write a file in the `/cache` directory? I continue to get a `FileNotFoundException (Permission denied)`.

Someone told me about the `android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM` but i can't find it [in the Android reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: i'm using level 13 apis

Answer (score 28):

You can only write to the cache directory of your own application: use  `context.getCacheDir()` to get its location.

Comment: Thank you clemp6r, but i need to write exactly the /cache directory (if possible) and not the one owned by the application.

Comment: You can't unless the device is rooted.

Comment: Thank you for your time clemp6r, not a solution for me but your is a great comment.

Comment: @clemp6r  what about a system app?